# Fields not displaying with three tables

Tags: crystal-reports

I am a REAL newbie to Crystal.  I have the following tables in the report:

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbooD.jpg)

The problem is that I cannot get the NAME field from the CUSTOMER table to show up in the report.  Very frustrating.  Any help?  Thanks!

Scott

Comment: what type of join have you used?

Comment: See, that's the problem.  I'm an ignorant newbie.  No formal training.  Just simple report mods that so far have gone just fine.  Sorry....  :(

Comment: try to use outer join for the table and check records coming or not